# How do i fill specific columns in a mutlidimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to fill the 2nd and 4th columns with zeros. I have achieved this so far, but i can't figure out why. In main i tried to fill the whole array with zeros. In random1 i tried to fill specific cells with random numbers. I used the `for (j=0;j<25;j=j+2)` in order to fill every second column with the random numbers, but still haven't achieved it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//int random1 (int );

int random1 (int b[5][5])
{
   int i,j;
   int *onedim = (int *)b; 
   srand(time(NULL));  
   for (j = 0; j < 25; j = j + 2)
       onedim[j] = rand() % 19 - 9; 
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
       {
           printf("%d\t", b[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");   
   }
   return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, j;
    int a[5][5];
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    random1(a);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: and what is the result you're getting? seems to work for me (I replaced the random by `444444` to see clearly

Comment: Your cast to `int *` invokes undefined behaviour. Why don't you use 2D indexing? nd format this mess properly. It is newr unreadable.

Comment: @Olaf: I wouldn't say so. As opposed to array of pointers, 2D arrays are contiguous. Casting to `int *` is okay.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Please read the standard. It clearly violates effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. Things would be different for a proper expression yielding `int *`!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Thanks, but it only fills the 2nd column with random. I wanted to fill it with 0. And by setting j=1;j<25;j=j+5 , i also filled with 0 all the other columns.

Comment: @Olaf okay. So how do you propose to cast `b` to a 1D pointer properly? I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why cast at all?? Never ever cast if there is a compliant way without. Think what the line is soppused to do. **Thhen** how it can be achieved. The solution is very obvious, just step back.

Comment: @Olaf: 1D array isn't useful here. I didn't understand that at first. I changed my answer. Not sure it is very useful now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's another issue, yes. But even iff, there was a way (I dont see it makes much sense in good code unless you use `mem*`, though). Just use nested loops and leave optimisations to the compiler. It might even generate code for a single loop. But after all, it** knows what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop is filling random numbers every other value, since you're incrementing by 2, in the "flattened" array. You can't keep track of the current row or column like this (or you have to use modulo, well, better stick to the 2D array in that case...)

The simplest way is to pick one column out of two, for each row (drop this 1D pointer idea that isn't useful here)

```
 for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    for (j=0;j<5;j+=2)
    {
       b[i][j] = 44444; // let's fix the value just to see clearly
    }
 }
```

I've made the test (and fixed the value so I see what's modified):

```
44444   0       44444   0       44444
44444   0       44444   0       44444
44444   0       44444   0       44444
44444   0       44444   0       44444
44444   0       44444   0       44444
```